# C, Is it possible to ASSIGN a macro to a structure variable?

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor

I'm new to embedded programming. I've got a PIC microcontroller with 2 header files: `pic.h` and `Timer_peripheral.h`.

In `pic.h` the timer configuration register has been defined as:

```
__extension__ typedef struct tagT1CONBITS {
union {
  struct {
    unsigned :1;
    unsigned TCS:1;
    unsigned TSYNC:1;
    unsigned :1;
    unsigned TCKPS:2;
    unsigned TGATE:1;
    unsigned :6;
    unsigned TSIDL:1;
    unsigned :1;
    unsigned TON:1;
  };

  struct {
    unsigned :4;
    unsigned TCKPS0:1;
    unsigned TCKPS1:1;
   };
};
} T1CONBITS;
```

and in `timer.h`, some macros have been defined as:

```
/* Timer1 Control Register (T1CON) Bit Defines */

#define T1_ON               0xffff      /* Timer1 ON */
#define T1_OFF              0x7fff      /* Timer1 OFF */
```

Which correspond with the microcontroller data sheet. `unsigned` type is 16 bits. I tried to assign T1_ON to my struct variable `T1CONBITS` in this way:

```
T1CONBITS=T1_ON   // which is wrong.
```

I know that i can initialize a struct, but I want to do an assignment in my main function and I don't want to do it using struct members like:

```
T1CONBITS.TCS=1; 
T1CONBITS.TSYNC=1;
```

Is there any way to do that? If not, why do you think these macros in `timer.h` have been defined?

Thanks for any insight

Comment: Do you only want to set the `TON` flag or all bits in `T1CONBITS`?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work because you're trying to assign a number to a variable of some completely unrelated type. The fact that the number matches the structure's underlying bit pattern is something the compiler doesn't care a whole lot about.

Try this:

```
union BitsInt {
    struct tagT1CONBITS con;
    int bits;
};

T1CONBITS = ((union BitsInt){ .bits = T1_ON }).con;
```

You put data of one type in, you get the same data of an unrelated type out.

(Using a union to cast bit patterns is valid as of up-to-date C standards.)

Comment: Yes, from a C perspective, but to make it work be sure the alternate type provided in the union will cause the compiler to encode operations which are compatible with the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

After pre-processing this

```
T1CONBITS=T1_ON;
```

would be this:

```
T1CONBITS=0xffff;
```

To are `struct` variable only a **variable** of the same type can by assigned.

---

You could easyly set `T1CONBITS` to all `1`s by doing so:

```
memset(&T1CONBITS, 0xff, sizeof(T1CONBITS));
```

Comment: This sets all _bytes_ in T1CONBITS to 1. That is completely useless. You probably meant to set all _bits_. `memset(&T1CONBITS, 0xFF, ...`

Comment: @Lundin: Aargh .. sure I meant this! Thanks for your comment. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the struct T1CONBITS indicates that it is intended for accessing the *bits* of T1CON.  Is there noat also defined a register T1CON wherby you can write the following?

```
T1CON = T1_ON ;
```

Better yet, you could simply use T1CONBITS as it was intended and avoif teh need to T1_ON and T1_OFF altogether:

```
T1CONBITS.TON = 0 ; // Off
T1CONBITS.TON = 1 ; // On
```

By assigning T1CON directly you are setting all other bits to 1 which is probably not what you intended in any case.  Rather you would read-modify-write, which is essentially what the bit access does only far less error prone and with greater clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, pre-made register maps delivered with the compiler for a certain microcontroller are burdensome, unreadable and non-portable, at best. Whether your particular code makes sense at all, nobody can tell, since bit fields are implemented differently on every compiler.

If you have the option to write the register definitions yourself, do so. For example:

```
#define T1CON (*(uint16_t*)0x1234u) // some address

#define T1CON_TCS    0x4000u
#define T1CON_TSYNC  0x2000u
...
#define T1CON_TCKPS  0x0C00u
```

and then set bits with standard C programming bit set idioms:

```
T1CON |=  T1CON_TCS; // set this bit
T1CON &= ~T1CON_TCS; // clear this bit
```

To set several bits belonging to the same group:

```
#define T1_ON  0x0C00u 
#define T1_OFF 0x0400u

T1CON |= (T1CON_TCKPS & T1_ON);
```

And so on.

(Though note that this will be read-modify-write, which may or may not be what you want. If you must use plain bit sets (for special cases, to clear flag registers etc), you typically leave out the bitwise logic and just write `T1CON =  T1CON_TCS | TSYNC;` with all the desired bits set. But note that there is no guartees, whether a certain C code gives read-modify-write or bit set is CPU and compiler dependent. Disassemble to ensure that the code does what you expected.)

This is 100% portable to every C compiler in the world, and 100% readable to every C programmer who works with embedded systems.